# How to sum a range of cells with N/A values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a range and need to sum it using SUM function but the result is N/A if there is any N/A value. How can I make the SUM function to treat the N/A value as 0 value? 
Please help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Array Formula

```
=SUM(IF(ISNA(A1:A4),0,A1:A4))
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the formula

Note: Replace `A1:A4` with your range

Comment: +1: A nice improvement on my solution - no need to modify the original data.

Comment: Nice. Never thought of using an array formula. I was happy with using =SUMIF(A1:A4, "<>#N/A") until I discovered it breaks if the spreadsheet is opened in a copy of Excel localised for another language! Unfortunately replacing "<>#N/A" with "ISNA()" doesn't work, but the array formula is a nice multilingual solution. Sadly, it's not a suitable approach for the same challenge with AVERAGEIF() … :-(

Comment: @JoeCarroll, you can use `=AVERAGE(IF(ISNA(A1:A4),"",A1:A4))`

Comment: Thanks @wilson ! When I considered it briefly I didn't think of using "" instead of zero, silly me :-) Using zero affects the sample size, of course, which led me to dismiss the solution, but empty cells are simply ignored.

Comment: Does not work with the magical Cr@pXcel 2013, but answer below (=aggregate) works like charm!

Comment: @Mark, agree that `=aggregate(...)` is a more elegant solution for excel 2010 and onwards. btw, i only have office 2010 / 2003 on hand, so i cannot test the array formula in 2013.

Comment: @wilson I wish I didn't have 2013 neither, but it's corp.policy :) It seems formulas work *like* interpreters (definition is incorrect on 'tech level', I know...) in 2013 so if you say something like "SUM A1:Ax IF A1:Ax [condition]..." excel stops processing on the 1st hit and ignores you want to SUM a range, not "SUM the first valid entry"(with itself?). Strange and ugly.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way:

Use `SUMIF` the value > 0.

So the syntax for that one is

`=SUMIF(A1:B2, "> 0")`

You will get the same result since it will ignore any non-numeric or 0 values.

Comment: Your suggestion won't work with negative numbers. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could do `=SUMIF(A1:B2, ">=0") + SUMIF(A1:B2, "<0")` to include negative numbers. I suspect that would be faster than the accepted array formula solution, if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 5):

There is a new function in Excel which will add all the values either positive or negative while ignoring NA's.

```
=aggregate(9,6, range of your data)
```

9 is used for sum while 6 is for ignoring all NA's. There are other options, as well, beside addition.  For example, you can do product, standard deviation, and so on.

More information on AGGREGATE [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF).

Comment: elegant solution for excel 2010 and onwards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the #N/A to zeros in your source range and then use the normal SUM function:

```
=IF(ISNA(OriginalFormula), 0, OriginalFormula)
```

Comment: Since office 2007 there's a new feature, `IFERROR`, and then it can look like this: `=IFERROR(OriginalFormula,0)` making it much nicer.

Comment: @agentmike, agreed, I use it frequently these days.

Answer (score 0):

If there are formulas I'd copy as numbers, replace #N/A in column with 0 and then sum as usually

Answer (score -1):

Use SUBTOTAL instead:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,A1:A50)
```

Comment: I'm trying `sumtotal` but I have the same problem than with `sum`

Answer (score -1):

This way it seems to work:

```
SUMIF(range;"<>#N/A";range)
```

Not so robust but effective!